# how to get the charachter at some specific index in GWT Text area

Tags: java, gwt, textarea, keyevent

I am trying to make a functionality of word suggestion in my textarea .

Like if a user enter  " this is test "  and press ctrl this should give user the options which matches  "test" .. like on press of ctrl it should give a popup with word "testing" for example.

for that what I need to get is the word on which user press ctrl.. i.e  "test"  in that case.

I was thinking to get the cursor index when user press ctrl.. and then go back until there is a space , til that index will be my word..

But I dont know how to get the character at some specified cursor index.

Any idea ..

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't [`TextArea#getCursorPos()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextArea.html#getCursorPos%28%29) what you're looking for?

This should do:

```
final TextArea area = new TextArea();
area.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event)
    {
        // Check if ctrl is pressed

        int position = area.getCursorPos();

        if(position > 0)
            System.out.println(area.getText().toCharArray()[position - 1]);
    }
});
```

That'll give you the position of the cursor. You can then use that information to get the character "in front" of the cursor.

---

If you can't figure out how to get the word, use this:

```
String text = area.getText();
char[] parts = text.toCharArray();
int startPosition = 0;

for(int i = position - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(parts[i] == ' ')
    {
        startPosition = i;
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println(text.substring(startPosition, position - 1));
```

You might need to fix the indices a bit to get the boundaries right.

Comment: thanks , is the syntax correct.. after  -1  its giving compilation error : error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Comment: @junaidp Yeah, just copy pasted it from compiled code. Did you maybe miss a bracket?

Comment: ok, error gone now , But this will give me "t"  as I press ctrl after writing "test",   But I need to have the complete word , in this case , System.out should display "test"

Comment: @junaidp Now come on, that's basic Java stuff. I'm confident you can figure that one out yourself :)